# orientDB database size is too big

Tags: orientdb, database, nosql

After inserting about 2 Million rows in orientDB, I noticed that the DB size has grown to almost 500 MB (even after I removed WALs). This database has just one class and vertex with 5 properties.

Similar database in SQLITE ws 16 MB in size. Is there something I can do to shrink the database size in Orient DB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any index on it? When you create the class you could use just 1 cluster (by default there are X files, where X is the number of cores). Try `drop class x` and then `create class x clusters 1`

Comment: Did you define indexes on properties? All the details about your schema should be provided, size and number of properties are not enough.